# How should I call a class in python?

Tags: python, class, ipython

I do these below steps to use a class in python but I couldn't succeed:

First, I make a class as following in a file named shape.py

```
class Shape:
    description = "This shape has not been described yet"
    author = "Nobody has claimed to make this shape yet"
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def area(self):
        return self.x * self.y
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.x + 2 * self.y
    def describe(self,text):
        self.description = text
    def authorName(self,text):
        self.author = text
    def scaleSize(self,scale):
        self.x = self.x * scale
        self.y = self.y * scale
```

Second, I go to terminal and open up python.

Third, I type

```
import shape
```

and finally, I write

```
rectangle = Shape(100, 45)
```

It doesn't work. Any suggestion?

The error message is `NameError: name 'Shape' is not define`

Comment: What error do you get? Post it please.

Comment: Define "It doesn't work."

Comment: try using `shape.Shape()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you `import shape`, all the functions, classes, and variables of the `shape` module are constrained to that "namespace"

So to instantiate from the `Shape` class, you need to call it under `shape.`, like this:

```
import shape
rectangle = shape.Shape(100, 45)
```

If you want to be able to access `Shape` without typing `shape.` in front, you can do this variation on the import:

```
from shape import Shape
rectangle = Shape(100, 45)
```

---

To be most clear, this is a function of `import`ing, not one specific to how to "call a class"